# Python read .LST file but skip page breakings text

Tags: python

I am receiving a .lst file and need to create a report. This file contains page-breaking sections and I would need to skip them. Since the file is a total mess and there is no option to recreate a table here, I am attaching an image as a demo.

[image]

Is there a solution of skipping the whole block of the page section between the pages and reading the file to get a final table like:

| Dat | Full Name | No | Enter | Pause Start | Pause End | Exit | Rate | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mo 2. | Some, Name | 1 | AllDay | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 7.40 |
| We 4. | Some, Name | 1 | 7:59 | 12:20 | 12:42 | 17:28 | 8.98 | 0.00 |
| Su 8. | Some, Name | 1 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

I started with:

```
word='XXX/WWW- Country' # skip reading this line ?
with open('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\file.lst') as f:
for line in f:
    if not word in line:
        print (line)
```

and stuck here since I don't know how to split this file due to desired output.

I tried to open this file via Pandas but get an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 306: invalid start byte.
I changed 'utf-8' with 'utf-16' but still nothing.

Any hints/tips?

Thank you in advance.